# How iOS central sends incoming calls and SMS notifications to peripheral using BTLE?

Tags: ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy

What I want to know is how could an iOS device acting as central, send information to a electronic device (not iOS device) acting as peripheral, when the iOS device is getting a SMS or an incoming call.

I have read many times that because of Apple's privacy policy, iOS does not allow detecting this, but how devices as coockoo watch respond to incoming calls and SMSs? These events must be detected somehow.

As far as I know these bluetooth devices use a dual bluetooth chip, so they must communicate with iOS device using Bluetooth Low Energy only.

Comment: are you able to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is available from the [Apple Notification Center Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH2-SW1) (ANCS)

Your iOS device must be operating as a peripheral, advertising at least one other service, before iOS will advertise the ANCS service.  Your display device operates as a Bluetooth central role and scans for the iOS device.

The solution could work something like this -

1. User runs an App (that you create) on their iOS device. The app allows them to advertise a particular service and some sort of identification string (pre-loaded with the user's device name for example)
2. Your display device scans for the service and retrieves the identification.  If it is a previously registered id then it starts monitoring the ANCS service and displaying notifications
3. If there is no previously registered id or the user has requested a "rescan" then the user is prompted as to whether they want to monitor the detected device e.g. "Monitor Paul's iPhone?" If they accept then return to step 2

You have to use an ID string as iOS will periodically change the device's UUID, so it can't be relied upon

Comment: How can i get the notification data and perform an action on the notification alert. Let say I want to blink an BLE LED on notification(SMS notification e.g.). Can I perform this? If yes please advice.

Comment: Yes you can do it, but how is a vey broad question. You would need to write the code to decode the ancs notification data and turn on the led

Comment: I have wriiten the code in which my iPhone act as Central and LED as Peripheral. Now where i get the notification data and how? I have gone through ANSC but not able to get the desired result.

Comment: To use ancs your phone is the peripheral and the other BLE device is the central. The device subscribes to the ancs service in the iPhone and gets notifications of events

Comment: I dont have LED firmware code so not able to subscribe the ANCS. Do we have another option to handle the notifications. I have seen same app performing the same operation.

Comment: The BLE device needs to subscribe to the ancs service. An app can't access notifications for other apps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102464/discussion-between-iprogrammer-and-paulw11).

Comment: Hi guys, I have the same problem as @iProgrammer , did you managed to find solution without making your wearable be the central? did you found a way to register to ANSC service within your app, parse the notification and pass the data to your peripheral (LED) ?

Comment: No, an app cannot connect to ancs